# angular typeahead $viewValue not updating after rename

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm using angular v.1.2.28 and I have a complex element that combines dropdown with typeahead:

```
<div class="btn-group vl-dropdown-container " style="width:100%" dropdown
                     ng-class="{disabledFunctionalityAndClick:isReadOnly}">

                    <a class="vl-dropdown-toggle vl-pf-dd-button" dropdown-toggle>
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>

                    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
                        <input placeholder="Select a discount table" class="vl-autocomplete  um-dd-input"
                               ng-model="selectedTypeaheadValue"
                               typeahead="discount as discount.id for discount in discountTablePool | filter:$viewValue"
                               typeahead-on-select="selectDiscountTable($item)"
                               typeahead-editable="false"
                               ng-blur="validateSelectedDiscount($viewValue)"/>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li ng-repeat="discountTable in discountTablePool track by $index">
                            <a href dropdown-toggle ng-click="selectDiscountTable(discountTable)">{{discountTable
                                .id}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
```

I also give the user an option to rename the currently selected value by clicking a button that opens a modal:

```
<a class="um-menu-label" ng-click="renameDiscountTable()">Rename              </a>
```

once the user updated the value and clicked ok i call this:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (data) {

                        if ($scope.selectedDiscountTable.id != data.name) {
                            if ($scope.selectedDiscountTable.isFromServer === true) {
                                //check if it was already renamed
                                var obj = _.find($scope.renamedDiscountTables, {newName: $scope.selectedDiscountTable.id});
                                if (obj) {
                                    obj.newName = data.name;
                                }
                                else {
                                    $scope.renamedDiscountTables.push({
                                        oldName: $scope.selectedDiscountTable.id,
                                        newName: data.name
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            $scope.selectedDiscountTable.id = data.name;
                          //THIS IS WHERE I CHANGE THE TYPEAHEAD MODEL VALUE    
                            $scope.selectDiscountTable($scope.selectedDiscountTable);
                        }


                }


 $scope.selectDiscountTable = function (discount) {
            $scope.selectedDiscountTable = discount;
            $scope.selectedTypeaheadValue = angular.copy($scope.selectedDiscountTable);
        };
```

The problem is that the model `($scope.selectedTypeaheadValue)` is updated, but the value displayed to the user is still the previous one, so if i renamed discount1 to be discount2 , the model updates but the user still sees discount1:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, your `$scope.selectDiscountTable` might be called outside the digest cycle, as it's being triggered from inside a deferred function. As this isn't an angular event, you'll probably have to trigger a re-digest manually to get the view in sync.

Try using `$scope.$evalAsync()` and update your $scope values inside of it.

Comment: Not sure it is true, since it's a ui-bootstrap modal, and it runs inside the angular loop. You can see I'm updating other $scope values as well and they are updated just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's a simple solution, all i had to do is change the ng-model in the html from: `ng-model="selectedTypeaheadValue"` to: `ng-model="selectedTypeaheadValue.id"`